# Adding data to a specific PhpMyAdmin account.. how to?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Currently, I am playing around with HTML, Php. The website is fairly simple at the moment with little to no security. I am attempting to update the table called users in MyPhpAdmin which is in the authentication folder, I am trying to update the user's competition field but am having struggles with changing a specific users competition field.

After searching through a few internet posts i still have not found a solution.

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");     
if (isset($_POST['competition'])) {


$sql = "INSERT INTO users
        (competition)
    VALUES('compname')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
header("location: home.php");
```

html

```
<div class="columnleft">
        <form method = "post" action="competition.php">
            <input type="submit" name="competition"     value="Join Comp1">

        </form>
    </div>
```

http://prntscr.com/m3g4u8
As seen in the print screen a new user is created with the everything blank but the competition name, how can I specify the user I change the information to?
I understand this may be very easy to and is a novice but regardless any help is appreciated. I also realise sqli is better than SQL etc. Many thanks

Comment: As a tip, try to start with PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  instead of mysqli.  It will help to avoid all of the issues/habits that can cause security problems when interacting with a DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to update the user's competition field [...] How can I specify the user I change the information to?

You don't  need  an `INSERT` query but an `UPDATE`. You need to know the unique id of the user that you want to modify.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (competition) VALUES('compname')";
```

To :

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET competition = 'compname'  WHERE id = ?";
```

Where the question mark is the id of the user to update.

Comment: however, I am attempting to get the current users id of the person logged in. Any clue for the best way for it? I have tried what I put below but it has not worked, just full of errors. Thanks ////  

 $userID = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $_SESSION['username'] ";
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET competition = 'compname'  WHERE id = $userID ";

Comment: How about : `"UPDATE users SET competition = 'compname'  WHERE id = " .  $_SESSION['username']` ?

Comment: That's what i have tried, http://prntscr.com/m3utdn and the same as you recommended but that still does not update the table. The help is much appreciated, but do you have any other suggestions?